Shredded beef in ragu- do I have to make any other adjustments
I’m planning on cooking Marcella Hazan’s slow cooked beef ragu recipe for my girlfriends birthday. She calls for ground chuck to be added after the carrots and celery and cooked until it just loses its raw red colour. She then adds milk and boils it off completely and then does the same with white wine. I cannot source ground chuck so I am planning to make this recipe using larger cuts of beef chuck and then shredding them right before adding the pasta. My question is: do I have to make any other adjustments to the recipe if I intend to do this, can I still cook the larger chunks of meat in milk and wine and will the total cooking time be impacted?

Also, I despise the taste of celery raw, will I be able to taste it in the sauce or does it just bulk it up?

Welcome to the site! What's the cooking time?

You say 'larger cuts of beef', but how large are you talking?  1" (2.5cm) cubes are going to be MUCH different than if you just try to cook it like a pot roast.  I would also advise shredding the meat at least 15-30 mins before you serve, so the meat soaks up more of the other flavors.  (a potato masher or similar makes quick work of it once it's fully tender).  It might be worth researching french 'ragout' recipes

If you can't get ground chuck, you could also go with some other ground beef instead of chunks of chuck. That should work in the recipe without any further adjustments.

A pulled beef ragu sounds like an improvement over the original recipe, as long as you cook the beef long enough to get tender. Your recipe doesn't specify how long it actually takes to boil off the milk and the wine, so I'll give you my own approach to this instead.
Chuck is a working cut, so needs a long cooking time, I would suggest at least 2 and a half hours, with at least 30 minutes of resting time. This is to allow all the connective tissue that makes the meat tough to break down into gelatin, if you don't give enough time the meat will be tough. Resting  will let it relax and you'll be able to shred it easily with a fork. I suspect the method in the recipe won't be long enough for that, I would modify it by cooking it in a casserole dish with a lid, following all the instructions on the stovetop until the wine is mostly cooked off. Then I would cover it and put it in a 325°F (160°C) oven for 2 and a half hours. Check it every 30-45 minutes to make sure it doesn't dry out, add a bit of boiling water if it does. After the cooking time take it out of the oven and let it sit for awhile, the meat will become super-tender. You can then shred it up, reheat it on the stovetop and serve it with your pasta.
Incidentally, I would use this method with ground chuck as well. This is because the connective tissue is still there with ground meat, you just don't notice it. A long, slow cooking time will make that super-tender as well and the gelatin will give you a silky sauce.
You could also make this a day or two ahead of time, and reheat on the day, it may even be better that way.
Regarding flavors, with that long a cooking time the celery will completely break down and you are unlikely to taste it. However, you can leave it out if you prefer, it will still be delicious.

Is there a reason you can't grind the meat yourself, like in a food processor? If you can't then I would decrease the amounts of liquids a little. Try starting with half or 3/4 the amount of milk (same for the wine). When it comes to cooking (and many other things), you can always add more but you can't always take away as easily. Then watch as it cooks. If it dries out before you're ready, add more, a little bit at a time, until you get what's desired.
I'm not familiar with that recipe, but the spices should be okay at the same amounts. That's a call you'll have to make by tasting as you go along.
I agree that chuck needs a long cooking time, but I'm not in total agreement with the resting time. I don't think that's really needed. It sounds like it would turn a fun dish into a chore. Again, taste as you go. Don't be afraid to use your fingers (LOL). And just be sure your sauce is the right consistency and color before you call it "dinner". Have fun and enjoy!
